# React, i18next and html attr lang

Tags: html, reactjs, attributes, i18next, lang

I use React+i18next and have two languages on my website.

How to make change HTML 'lang' attribute on my page?

I use i18next-browser-languagedetector but lang attr does not change

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this question.

I added this in my App.js file:

> `document.documentElement.lang = i18n.language;`

Comment: Bravo! what an elegant solution

Comment: i18n.language returns the long ISO language code such as tr-TR, en-US, en-GB, etc. which is not a standard value for the html lang attribute. i18n.resolvedLanguage should be used instead, so that it returns the short language code like en, tr, fr... etc.

Comment: Alex Court's solution works for me, but setting `document.documentElement.lang = i18n.language` in my `_app.js` gives the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using your interface to allow a user to select/change the active language for `i18n`, then here is a way to add a callback to the `i18n` instance to keep the html lng tag in sync with i18n.

```js
i18n.on('languageChanged', (lng) => (document.documentElement.lang = lng))
```